# SQLAlchemy Faster Than Psycopg2. What's Wrong with My Benchmark?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

First, I create a table with 5 columns:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
  a integer,
  b character varying,
  c character varying,
  d numeric,
  e numeric
)
```

Second, I add 100k rows to a table

https://gist.github.com/ericsalim/1d12628826195b52c5d282c2326f5e00

Third, I select all the rows using Psycopg2 and SQLAlchemy

- Using Psycopg2: https://gist.github.com/ericsalim/f45d0f0d4babf0e59708c75804eb78c4
- Using SQLAlchemy: https://gist.github.com/ericsalim/c8df8adeb9ec49fa8cb1b5c5e8d811f8

The result for Psycopg2

- query time: 2839.46800232
- conversion time: 792.379140854
- res size: 400036
- rowlist size: 412232

The result for SQLAlchemy:

- query time: 2401.74889565
- conversion time: 377.213001251
- res size: 412232
- rowlist size: 412232

How is it possible that SQLAlchemy, which is an ORM layer on top Psycopg2 is faster than Psycopg2 itself? Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: You do not use ORM here, the code is the same, you just use another way to connect to DB. Try to use python profilers, maybe you will find the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the overhead of the `DictCursor`. Switching it to use a standard cursor and integer indices results in `psycopg2` outperforming. I imagine SQLAlchemy uses a different, more efficient method for supporting string indexes. But other than academic curiosity, I would not worry about the performance difference between the two - focus on which is more productive for you. In most real-world scenarios, you will be I/O bound, and the difference is small enough to not matter.

Comment: Thank you. Removing DictCursor makes it faster than SQLAlchemy. I guess this means SQLAlchemy is very efficient :)